# Create a shared folder in Dropbox with dropbox-core-sdk-2.0-beta-4 and then add a member to it

Tags: dropbox-api

I am trying to create a shared folder in a dropbox account, from a Java desktop application by using the dropbox-core-sdk-2.0-beta-4, with the code below, but I am getting these exceptions:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:     com.dropbox.core.json.JsonWriter.writeFields(Ljava/lang/Object;Lcom/fasterxml/jack son/core/JsonGenerator;)V
at com.dropbox.core.v2.DbxFiles$CreateFolderArg$1.write(DbxFiles.java:5337)
at com.dropbox.core.v2.DbxFiles$CreateFolderArg$1.write(DbxFiles.java:5332)
at com.dropbox.core.json.JsonWriter.writeToStream(JsonWriter.java:23)
at com.dropbox.core.json.JsonWriter.writeToStream(JsonWriter.java:33)
at com.dropbox.core.v2.DbxRawClientV2.rpcStyle(DbxRawClientV2.java:82)
at com.dropbox.core.v2.DbxFiles.createFolder(DbxFiles.java:8459)
at com.dropbox.core.v2.DbxFiles.createFolder(DbxFiles.java:8479)
```

My code is the following:

```
DbxRequestConfig dbxRequestConfig = new DbxRequestConfig("test/1.0",     Locale.getDefault().toString());
DbxClientV2 dbxClient = new DbxClientV2(dbxRequestConfig, my_access_token);

FolderMetadata md = dbxClient.files.createFolder("/test");

ArrayList<AddMember> list = new ArrayList();
DbxSharing.AddMember a1 = new       DbxSharing.AddMember(DbxSharing.MemberSelector.email("xxxxxx@gmail.com"),
DbxSharing.AccessLevel.editor);

list.add(a1);
dbxClient.sharing.addFolderMember(md.parentSharedFolderId, list);
```

My code is heating at:

```
FolderMetadata md = dbxClient.files.createFolder("/test");
```

I have already search for any solution to create a shared folder and add a member to it, but I am not finding anything useful to my case.

Could anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: [Cross-linking for reference: https://www.dropboxforum.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/204631946-create-a-folder-that-will-be-shared-and-add-a-member-to-it- ]